# 従テーブルのクエリーセットによるページネーションを実装したい

Tags: python, django

#### 実現したいこと

Djangoで日記アプリケーションを作成しています。マイページ上でプロフィールだけでなく、自分が投稿した記事の一覧を併せて表示させており、表示させる記事の数を最大6にして、それ以降はページネーションによって記事を分割表示しようとしています。

#### 前提

**モデル**
・主モデルCustomUserに対して、従モデルArticleが一対多でリレーションシップ関係を取っています
・Articleモデルのリレーションフィールド(post_user)では、下記サイトを参考に、テンプレート側で逆参照を出来るように、related_nameオプションを設定しています
https://qiita.com/ragnar1904/items/1afaeb6601cc490fb70a#%E9%80%86%E5%8F%82%E7%85%A7%E3%81%AE%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88

```py
#models.py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(
        _("username"),
        max_length=30,
        help_text='Required 30 characters or fewer.',
        unique=True,
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("This Username already exists."),
        },)

    email = models.EmailField(
        _('email'),
        unique=True,
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that email address already exists."),
        },)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'CustomUser'


class Article(models.Model):
    post_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, verbose_name='Post User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='name',)
    title = models.TextField(verbose_name='title', max_length=50,)
    content = MDTextField()
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(verbose_name='thumbnail', null=False, blank=False,)
```

**ビュー**
・ビューではListViewを継承し、クラス変数`model`にはCustomUserを指定し、クラス変数`paginate_by`の指定も行う
・get_queryset()のオーバーライドでは、マイページのユーザに紐づくArticleモデルのクエリーセットをテンプレートへ渡すようにする

```py
#views.py
class MyPageView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'mypage.html'
    model = CustomUser
    paginate_by = 6
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        articles = CustomUser.objects.filter(username=self.request.user).prefetch_related('name')
        return articles
```

**テンプレート**
・テンプレートでは、主テーブルCustomUserのクエリを`{% for s in customuser_list %}`で取り出し、従テーブルArticleのクエリを`{% for article in s.name.all %}`で取り出す。

```html
<!--mypage.html-->
{% for s in customuser_list %}
<section class="u-content-space">
  <div class="container">
    <header class="text-center w-md-50 mx-auto mb-8">
      <h2 class="h1">Prototyping Works by {{ s.username }}</h2>
    </header>

    <div class="js-shuffle u-portfolio row no-gutters mb-6">
      {% for article in s.name.all %}
      <figure class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 u-portfolio__item" data-groups='["its-illustration"]'>
        <img class="u-portfolio__image_original" src="{{ article.thumbnail.url }}" alt="Image Description">
        <figcaption class="u-portfolio__info">
          <h6 class="mb-0">{{ article.title }}</h6>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      {% endfor %}
    
    <!--ページネーション処理-->
    {% if is_paginated %}
    <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center mb-4">
      <div class="col-lg">
        <nav aria-label="Bootstrap Pagination Example">
          <ul class="pagination mb-0">
            <!--前ページへのリンク-->
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <li class="page-item">
              <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">
              <span class="mr-1 d-none d-sm-inline-block">&larr;</span> Previous
              </a>
            </li>
            {% endif %}

            <!--ページ数表示-->
            {% for page_num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
              {% if page_obj.number == page_num %}
                <li class="page-item active">
                  <a class="page-item" href="#">{{ page_num }}</a>
                </li>
              {% else %}
                <li class="page-item">
                  <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_num }}">{{ page_num }}</a>
                </li>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

            <!--次ページへのリンク-->
            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
              <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">
                  Next<span class="ml-1 d-none d-sm-inline-block">&rarr;</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    
  </div>
</section>
{% endfor %}
```

#### 発生している問題

paginate_byで指定した値を上回る数の記事が表示され、さらにページネーションに関わる表示も一切ありませんでした。

ブラウザの検証ツールを用いてhtmlを確認してみたところ、ページネーションに関するコードが記載されていなかった為、テンプレートの`{% if is_paginated %}`がFalseだと判定されたのだと理解しました。

原因はviewsでページネーションに関するメソッドのオーバーライドで一工夫する必要があるかと考えましたが、調べても同じような事例を見つけることができず、どうすれば良いのか頭を抱えています。

#### 試したこと

・ブラウザのキャッシュを削除し再度読み込みを行なってもページネーションの表示がされることはありませんでした。
・下記のページを参考にget_paginate_byをオーバーライドしましたが、ブラウザ上の表示は変わりませんでした。
https://teratail.com/questions/243787

```
def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
        return self.request.GET.get('paginate_by', MyPageView.paginate_by)
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

開発環境は下記の通りです
・python 3.7.6
・Anacondaローカル内
・Django3系
・MacOS
・Chromeブラウザ